# Вторая рамка вокруг ячеек таблицы в Chrome, как убрать?

Tags: html, css, css3

Создаю таблицу используя свойство `display: table`. У ячеек таблицы есть своя рамка толщиной 5px, и свойство `border-radius`. В браузере Chrome (только) вокруг рамок ячеек появляется ещё одна рамка толщиной 1px (которая при масштабировании исчезает и видна только в местах скругления рамок ячеек, как на скриншоте). Как избавится от нее?

```html
<div class="table">
    <ul class="table-row">
        <li class="table-cell">1</li>
        <li class="table-cell">1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="table-row">
        <li class="table-cell">1</li>
        <li class="table-cell">1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: #514B48;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 90px;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 5px solid #514B48;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1e1c20;
    color: #fff;
    width: 90px;
    min-width: 90px;
    line-height: 80px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image: Вторая рамка при масштабировании]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не совсем удачный пример, но принцип, как убрать этот баг, думаю будет понятен

```
<div class="table">
    <ul class="table-row">
        <div class="box">
            <li class="table-cell">1</li>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <li class="table-cell">1</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <ul class="table-row">
        <div class="box">
            <li class="table-cell">1</li>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <li class="table-cell">1</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Стили:

```
<style>
    .table {
            display: table;
            margin: 50px auto;
            background: #514B48;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .table-row {
            display: table-row;
            height: 90px;
    }
    .box {
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
    }
    .table-cell {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            background: #1e1c20;
            color: #fff;
            width: 90px;
            min-width: 90px;
            line-height: 80px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
            -moz-border-radius: 8px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
```

[image: Результат]